# glassfish deployment error

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3, java-6

I have a java web project. Deploying and using my project is fine on my local machine, but when i deploy the project on my server, I get the following error when i upload my war file in the glassfish admin:

```
[#|2012-02-06T20:44:00.810+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.                                                                                                                                    server|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Installation Problem???  Couldn't load messages: Can't find bun                                                                                                                                    dle for base name com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.message, locale en_US
java.lang.RuntimeException: Installation Problem???  Couldn't load messages: Can't find bundle for base n                                                                                                                                    ame com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.message, locale en_US
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.RegexParser.setLocale(RegexParser.java:93)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.RegexParser.<init>(RegexParser.java:83)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.ParserForXMLSchema.<init>(ParserForXMLSche                                                                                                                                    ma.java:32)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.RegularExpression.setPattern(RegularExpres                                                                                                                                    sion.java:3002)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.RegularExpression.setPattern(RegularExpres                                                                                                                                    sion.java:3015)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.RegularExpression.<init>(RegularExpression                                                                                                                                    .java:2981)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.xs.XSSimpleTypeDecl.applyFacets(XSSimpleTypeDecl.ja                                                                                                                                    va:801)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.xs.XSSimpleTypeDecl.applyFacets(XSSimpleTypeDecl.ja                                                                                                                                    va:699)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDSimpleTypeTraverser.getSimpleType(XSD                                                                                                                                    SimpleTypeTraverser.java:386)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDSimpleTypeTraverser.traverseSimpleTyp                                                                                                                                    eDecl(XSDSimpleTypeTraverser.java:142)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDSimpleTypeTraverser.traverseGlobal(XS                                                                                                                                    DSimpleTypeTraverser.java:102)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseSchemas(XSDHandler.ja                                                                                                                                    va:1267)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:5                                                                                                                                    79)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:552                                                                                                                                    )
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValid                                                                                                                                    ator.java:2436)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaVali                                                                                                                                    dator.java:1781)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.                                                                                                                                    java:705)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumen                                                                                                                                    tScannerImpl.java:400)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootEleme                                                                                                                                    ntHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:626)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.n                                                                                                                                    ext(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3103)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentSc                                                                                                                                    annerImpl.java:922)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.jav                                                                                                                                    a:648)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl                                                                                                                                    .java:140)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumen                                                                                                                                    tFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:80                                                                                                                                    8)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:73                                                                                                                                    7)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205                                                                                                                                    )
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:5                                                                                                                                    22)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:3                                                                                                                                    06)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ExtensionsArchivist.open(ExtensionsArchivist.java:127)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.PersistenceArchivist.readPersistenceDeploymentDescript                                                                                                                                    or(PersistenceArchivist.java:128)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.WarPersistenceArchivist.open(WarPersistenceArchivist.j                                                                                                                                    ava:91)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readRestDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java                                                                                                                                    :393)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:383                                                                                                                                    )
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:246)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:255)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:216)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java                                                                                                                                    :165)
        at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:181)
        at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:93)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:828)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.jav                                                                                                                                    a:770)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:368)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:382)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1045)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:                                                                                                                                    1244)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:                                                                                                                                    1232)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:202)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:195)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResourc                                                                                                                                    e.java:148)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3157.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:6                                                                                                                                    0)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$Respon                                                                                                                                    seOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(Resourc                                                                                                                                    eJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.ja                                                                                                                                    va:84)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.ja                                                                                                                                    va:1469)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.ja                                                                                                                                    va:1400)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.jav                                                                                                                                    a:1349)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.jav                                                                                                                                    a:1339)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:1                                                                                                                                    82)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:14                                                                                                                                    7)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:184)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
|#]
```

Has anyone an idea why my project just work local?
thank you

Comment: Have you checked the server log file?

Comment: the log files in the glassfish admin are just showing the logs of running applications. where can i find the los for the deployment?

Comment: Depending on whether it's a single instance or a cluster that can vary, but something like:  <glassfish>/domains/domain1/logs  or  <glassfish>/nodes/<node-name>/<instance-name>/logs

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're missing libraries. This may happen if:

- your GlassFish versions are different in local and production environments.
- production is missing some external, server-level or domain-level library you have added in local.

Another cause may be your glassfish-web.xml/sun.web.xml having

```
<class-loader delegate="false"/>
```

which means that your WAR won't delegate class loading to GlassFish's classloader (so all necessary classes should be within the WAR itself). I was having this same issue with GlassFish v2.1.1 and solved the problem by setting classloader delegation to true, restarting the server and retrying WAR deployment.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error trying to deploy to a production version of GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1 (build 43).

A combination of:

- setting the  in the application's WEB-INF/sun-web.xml file. (It was true and I changed it to false.  Sadly this is opposite in sense to the other answer given.)
- and restarting the Glassfish server cleared the error and the application deployed.

I wish I had separated out these attempts, but I'm not able to easily do so now.

My local Glassfish server IS a different version: 3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I occasionally get this problem inside Netbeans when I run a project setup to use GlassFish 2.1.1 directly after running another one using 2.1.  Stopping both versions and rebuilding projects sometimes works, but I have found it better to just stick with one version of Glassfish for all projects.